# HOW to `AS IF()` statement query mariaDB?

Tags: sql, mariadb, alias

How can I create an alias in my query

```
SELECT
  LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) AS IF(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE())=31,'31','X')
```

Answer (score 1):

> Databases, tables, indexes, columns, ***aliases***, views, stored
> routines, triggers, events, variables, partitions, tablespaces,
> savepoints, labels, users, roles, are collectively known as
> identifiers, and have certain rules for naming.

(source: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-names/ )

The answer to your question is that you cannot have a dynamic alias because an alias is an identifier. An identifier can only have 1 name, and not a choice of names.

EDIT: When using something like [Dynamic Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dynamic-columns/) you still have only 1 column name, see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=b6517305b3509b74996b3a27057d3be3)

Comment: And what if the table has [Dynamic Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dynamic-columns/)? *(never tried it myself)*

Comment: All columns will still have only one name, see the edit.

Comment: Yeah, figured it would be like that. Thanks.